# How to manage freeable memory on AWS RDS MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

As stated in the title, I want to manage freeable memory on AWS RDS server. I was told that low memory on the RDS server does not really matter on the performance, but the swap usage does matter on the performance (If the swap usage is high, it might cause problems like latency on query). And its server will try to secure its minimum memory available by clearing old memory.

As far as I understand, the memory is consumed because of cached queries. So I came up with a temporary solution that I disabled query cache by setting `query_cache_type` to `0` in Parameter group. (There is no need to cache query result at this point)

However, for the future, I would like to manage its memory more efficiently. Is there any way to restore its memory without reboot (I notice freeable memory is restored whenever the server reboots) or to set a minimum threshold which the server tries to secure its minimum freeable memory threshold?

If I have a wrong understanding on any part I mentioned above, please feel free to correct me.

Any suggestion or advice would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: @BryceH I'm using MySQL 5.6.27

Comment: Please provide details of the freeable and swap amounts that are causing your concern so we can better recommend optimizations.

Comment: Right now I'm using t2.small instance. When normal state, swap usuage is around 16MB and freeable memory is around 1200MB. However, I experience whenever freeable memory is low (around 100MB), swap usage spikes up sometimes. And it causes latency on query, thus to the system.

Comment: The query cache uses a fixed buffer that is allocated at startup.  It should have zero impact on freeable memory, other than reducing the *baseline* memory usage of MySQL, and "cached queries" definitely do not make it grow.  It is static in size.  You can also reduce the baseline memory footprint by changing `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you for the comment. If "cached queries" do not have an impact on memory, what does? Why does the memory used keep growing?